How to Use Azure File Share to Automatically Copy Files to Windows VMSS Instances?
What is the best way to use Azure File Share to automatically copy files to a directory on Windows Virtual Machine Scale Set (VMSS) instances?
I have successfully used the following command to execute a custom script extension on my Windows VMSS instances:
az vmss extension set --vmss-name "webapparray1" --name "CustomScriptExtension" --resource-group "test" --version "1.10" --publisher "Microsoft.Compute" --settings "{\"fileUris\": [\"https://storagename.file.core.windows.net/scripts/FileShare.ps1\"], \"commandToExecute\": \"powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Fileshare.ps1\"}" --protected-settings "{\"storageAccountName\": \"storagename\", \"storageAccountKey\": \"a...euw==\"}"

This works well for running the script, but now I need to ensure that files from the Azure File Share are automatically copied to the VMSS instances' directories.
What steps or configurations do I need to set up for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Hi @shdr, I hope this helps to resolve your issue.


How to Use Azure File Share to Automatically Copy Files to Windows VMSS Instances?

Here is the PowerShell script to mount the file share on VMSS instances, initiate the copy to the local drive from the file share after mounting, and disconnect the drive once the copy is complete
Fileshare.ps1

# Variables
$targetDirectory = "C:\Fileshare data"
$mountDrive = "L:"  # The drive letter where the file share is mounted

# Mount the Azure File Share
$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "venkatrgaebd.file.core.windows.net" -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
    # Save the password so the drive will persist on reboot
    cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"venkatrgaebd.file.core.windows.net`" /user:`"localhost\venkatrgaebd`" /pass:`"TIwD7+kLzjq4dkX18nMnYDC94SesFesFNUu1XmnsfsjYEj8ftsjgq3RFc4ob6nXdZBtPhny934ax+AStnzZucg==`""

    # Mount the drive
    New-PSDrive -Name L -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\venkatrgaebd.file.core.windows.net\venkatfileshare" -Persist
} else {
    Write-Error "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Ensure your network allows access to port 445."
    exit
}

# Wait for a few seconds to ensure the mounted drive is ready
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

# Ensure the target directory ("Fileshare data") exists
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $targetDirectory)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $targetDirectory
}

# Copy files from the mounted Azure File Share to the target directory
try {
    # Use the correct path for the mounted drive: K:\
    Copy-Item -Path "$mountDrive\*" -Destination $targetDirectory -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "Files copied successfully from $mountDrive to $targetDirectory"
} catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to copy files. Error: $_"
}

# Optionally, unmount the file share after copying
try {
    Remove-PSDrive -Name "L"
    Write-Host "Drive L: unmounted successfully."
} catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to remove the drive. Error: $_"
}

You can place the script (Fileshare.ps1) in GitHub or Azure Blob Storage. If you upload the script to Blob Storage, add the storage account and access key details in the VMSS Extension command.
Command to create VMSS Extension
az vmss extension set --vmss-name "Venkat" --name "CustomScriptExtension" --resource-group "Venkat_group" --version "1.10" --publisher "Microsoft.Compute" --settings '{"fileUris": ["https://venkatrgaebd.blob.core.windows.net/venkat/Fileshare.ps1"], "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Fileshare.ps1"}' --protected-settings '{"storageAccountName": "venkatrgaebd", "storageAccountKey": "Zucg=="}'

Output

Fileshare data

After creating the VMSS extension, the same data will be copied to the VMSS instance

Reference:  az vmss extension set

Hi @Venkat, Very Informative answer.
Are you assuming it's a managed identity?
Because I can't get the permissions from protected-settings inside the VMSS instance.
What could be the problem?
When the permissions are hard-coded it works fine
I don't really understand how localhost\venkatrgaebd works.

When you create a fileshare in Azure and connect to it, it will generate the powershell code automatically. protected-settings is designed to securely store sensitive data (e.g., secrets, storage account keys).

In your case, using a public GitHub repo for the script, consider using the same github instead of blob storage for deployment.

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.

I don't want to leave permissions in plain text and I can't get the protected-settings properly on the machine the way you described.

The output after the CLI command show "protectedSettings": null

If you do not want to include the storage keys in the script, you can use the RBAC method and grant the necessary permissions to mount the fileshare. If there is an error while using protected Please provide the CLI command that you are using with error screenshot by editing the Qns.

I edited the protected-setting argument.

As I can see, you are using some extra slash. Use my command without slash.

Also not resolve on:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14095
https://github.com/Azure/autorest.go/issues/946

Are you using GitHub or an Azure storage account? If it's a storage account, you can use the script I provided in the answer. az vmss extension set --vmss-name "Venkat" --name "CustomScriptExtension" --resource-group "Venkat_group" --version "1.10" --publisher "Microsoft.Compute" --settings '{"fileUris": ["https://venkatrgaebd.blob.core.windows.net/venkat/Fileshare.ps1"], "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Fileshare.ps1"}' --protected-settings '{"storageAccountName": "venkatrgaebd", "storageAccountKey": "Zucg=="}'

Have you tried it? i got: *Failed to parse string as JSON:
'{fileUris:
Error detail: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Please provide a valid JSON file path or JSON string.
The provided JSON string may have been parsed by the shell. See https://docs.microsoft.com/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#use-quotation-marks-in-arguments* probebly it is not recognize the double quotes

Yes, working for me.To pass a blob URL in a script, go to storage account > Blob storage > select the script blob and generate the SAS token> there you will get the URL with access key, then copy the same URL and paste it in the fileuri section.
